# AttributeError: can't set attribute when trying to increment X value of a circle in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm having a lot of trouble creating a simple function that increments the X value of a circle's center with sympy. Here's my code:

```
test_center=Point (1,2)
test_circle = Circle (test_center, 1)

def travel (circle, distance):

    circle.center.x += distance
    return circle.center.x

travel (test_circle,1)
print(test_circle)
```

What I get back is:

line 16, in travel

> circle.center.x += distance AttributeError: can't set attribute

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I hope you'll mark the answer accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `circle.center.x` can not be assigned, if you want to move the circle use the translate function:

```
from sympy import Point, Circle

test_center=Point (1,2)
test_circle = Circle (test_center, 1)

def travel (circle, distance):
    return circle.translate(x=distance)


test_circle = travel(test_circle,1)
print(test_circle)
```