# AttributeError: can't set attribute when trying to increment X value of a circle in sympy[2] I want 3Pattern

Tags: sympy

I want 3Pattern ①②➂

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/points.html#sympy.geometry.point.Point2D.x

[AttributeError: can't set attribute when trying to increment X value of a circle in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42639847/attributeerror-cant-set-attribute-when-trying-to-increment-x-value-of-a-circle)

```
from sympy import Point, Circle
def myPointSubs(PT,x,y):
    return PT.translate(x=-PT.x+x,y=-PT.y+y)
test_center=Point (1,2)
test_circle=Circle(myPointSubs(test_center,2,test_center.y), 1)
# test_circle=Circle(myPointSubs(test_center,2,), 1) #①　I want Circle(Point2D(2,2), 1)
# test_circle=Circle(myPointSubs(test_center,,1), 1) #②　I want Circle(Point2D(1,1), 1)
# test_circle=Circle(myPointSubs(test_center,, ), 1) #➂　I want Circle(Point2D(1,2), 1)
print("#",test_circle)
# Circle(Point2D(2, 2), 1)
```

test_circle=Circle(myPointSubs(test_center,2,), 1)

TypeError: myPointSubs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

(2021-12-28)

```
from sympy import Point
def change(pt,x=None,y=None):
    return pt.func(pt.x if x is None else x, pt.y if y is None else y)
print("#",change(Point(1, 2), y=3))
print("#",change(Point(1, 2), x=3))
print("#",change(Point(1, 2), 3))
print("#",change(Point(1, 2), 2, 1))
print("")
print("#1",change(Point(1, 2)   ))
# print("#2",change(Point(1, 2),, ))         #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
# print("#3",change(Point(1, 2),,4))         #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
print("#4",change(Point(1, 2), x=3,y=4))
print("#5",change(Point(1, 2), y=4,x=3))
print("#6",change(Point(1, 2),3,))

# Point2D(1, 3)
# Point2D(3, 2)
# Point2D(3, 2)
# Point2D(2, 1)

#1 Point2D(1, 2)
#     print("#2",change(Point(1, 2),, ))         #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#                                   ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#     print("#3",change(Point(1, 2),,4))         #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#                                   ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
#4 Point2D(3, 4)
#5 Point2D(3, 4)
#6 Point2D(3, 2)
```

google > python none default argument

```
from sympy import *
def change(pt,x=None,y=None):
    return pt.func(pt.x if x is None else x, pt.y if y is None else y)
test_center =Point (1,2)
test_circle =Circle(change(test_center,2,test_center.y), 1)
test_circle1=Circle(change(test_center,x=2),1) #① I want Circle(Point2D(2,2), 1)
test_circle2=Circle(change(test_center,y=1),1) #② I want Circle(Point2D(1,1), 1)
test_circle3=Circle(change(test_center    ),1) #➂ I want Circle(Point2D(1,2), 1)
print("# ",test_circle )
print("#1",test_circle1)
print("#2",test_circle2)
print("#3",test_circle3)

#  Circle(Point2D(2, 2), 1)
#1 Circle(Point2D(2, 2), 1)
#2 Circle(Point2D(1, 1), 1)
#3 Circle(Point2D(1, 2), 1)
```

Comment: Reread the `myPointSubs(PT,x,y)` function definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle optional args is to give them a default None value and then handle the case when they are None or not in the function:

```
>>> from sympy import Point
>>> def change(pt,x=None,y=None):
...   return pt.func(pt.x if x is None else x, pt.y if y is None else y)
...
>>> change(Point(1,2),y=3)
Point2D(1, 3)
>>> change(Point(1,2),x=3)
Point2D(3, 2)
>>> change(Point(1,2),3)
>>> change(Point(1,2),2,1)
Point2D(2, 1)
```

The error you get should be (in retrospect) self explanatory: the function expected an arg that you did not supply: it expected 3 args and you gave it 2. In the function I defined, by defining default arg values, it won't complain when I don't give it all the args...but if I want to change y and not x, I can't just use `pt,,yval`; I have to pass the `yval` as `y=yval`.